# Linear Algebra: Help me word something?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The question I was given asked me if a 3x5 coefficient matrix with three pivot columns would be consistent or not. Since I'm dealing with a coefficient matrix, regardless of its augmented form, it is consistent. This is because for each row, there exists a variable whose coefficient is not zero. I can't argue using free variables, as that would force me to make assumptions that aren't given within the problem. Please help me word this answer? Or is my two sentence blurb above sufficient? Thank you!

Comment: I don't know, depends on the context. If the matrix represents multiple systems rather than just one, it could still be inconsistent.

Comment: It represents a single system only. I apologize for the vagueness!

Comment: Well, with that I agree it is consistent since three pivot columns forbids a leading 1 being in the last row. You could argue the same for a $3 \times 4$. The key is there is no leading one in the inhomogeneous columns which represents as an equation $0=1$.

Comment: If you have the linear correspondence or column correspondence to work with, you can also argue it is clear the last column is a linear combination of the pivot columns hence the system clearly permits a solution. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h82jdvCaNGU&index=11&list=PLBY4G2o7DhF1GaQaG4haiIGKk9qEYxCZQ for more on the column correspondence property I mention...

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot. ^-^